# Syntax Conflict in Angular App When Declaring Variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function that I use to handle pagination in my Angular app. It was working as expected - I subscribe to the url params and then use the router to navigate according to those params while taking in the page number as a passed in value. One param is a boolean indicating whether the filter is currently active, and the second param is the value(s) itself for the filter.

This is the working version:

```
public paginate(page) {
  this.route.params.subscribe(
    (params: any) => {
      this.pn_location_e = params['pn_location_e'];
      this.pn_location_v = params['pn_location_v'];
    }
  );

  this.router.navigate(
    ['/clients', {
      page: page,
      pn_location_e: this.pn_location_e,
      pn_location_v: this.pn_location_v,
    }]);

  let fn = resRecordsData => {
    this.records = resRecordsData;
    let data = resRecordsData.data;
  };

  this.dataService.filterByInput(
    page - 1, this.pagesize, this.location, fn);
}
```

Everything above was working as expected.

However, recently a colleague changed the filter syntax from using an "_" to using a ".". So it went from this:

```
this.pn_location_e = params['pn_location_e'];
```

to this:

```
this.pn_location.e = params['pn_location.e'];
```

The problem is, in my Angular component I can't initialize the variable with that syntax. When I try and initialize like this:

```
pn_location.e
```

... I get a syntax error. I also tried doing this `pn_location['.e']`, but that also won't work (also causes a syntax error).

Is there a way around this? Or do we just need to go back to using the underscore syntax for our filters params?

Comment: Can you provide the exact syntax error that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surrounding the property names with quotes will allow the assignments:

```
public paginate(page) {
  this.route.params.subscribe(
    (params: any) => {
      this.pn_location_e = params['pn_location.e'];
      this.pn_location_v = params['pn_location.v'];
    }
  );

  this.router.navigate(
    ['/clients', {
      page: page,
      'pn_location.e': this.pn_location_e,
      'pn_location.v': this.pn_location_v,
    }]);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @ConnorsFan!